# how to make chat icon in android?

Tags: android, icons, chat

How to make chat icon stuff really I have no idea how to do that 
does it really need a database or import all icons to drawable folder ?

is there any way to do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to put all of the icons in a drawable folder so you can easily access them.

Answer (score 1):

The icons are added to the res/drawable folder. There are multiple folders, you should have different versions of your icon depending on the folder.
Read [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

You can use the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) to scale your icons